# ReactiveUI - ReactiveCommand fails when ToProperty is fine on the same Observable

Tags: c#, reactive, reactiveui

I have a ReactiveCommand that throws the following error.

> An object implementing IHandleObservableErrors (often a
>   ReactiveCommand or ObservableAsPropertyHelper) has errored, thereby
>   breaking its observable pipeline. To prevent this, ensure the pipeline
>   does not error, or Subscribe to the ThrownExceptions property of the
>   object in question to handle the erroneous case.

Here is the code (method A):

```
private List<Dto> _items;
public List<Dto> Items
{
    get => _items;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _items, value);
}
RefreshCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() => GetItems
                    .Do(dtos => Items = dtos)
                    .Select(_ => Unit.Default))
                .DisposeWith(Disposables);
RefreshCommand.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(err => Console.WriteLine(err.ToString()));
RefreshCommand.ExecuteIfPossible();
```

I aslo tried something else (method B):

```
private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<List<Dto>> _items;
public List<Dto> Items => _items.Value;
this._items = GetItems.ToProperty(this, x => x.Items);
```

My questions are:

1. Why is method A throwing an error if I subscribed to `ThrownExceptions`? Note that `Console.WriteLine(err.ToString())` is never hit.
2. Why is method B working fine knowing method A fails?

I'm using [Uno.ReactiveUI](https://github.com/nventive/Uno.ReactiveUI) which is a forks of reactiveUI version 8.0.0

Thank you.

UPDATE

If I comment out `ExecuteIfPossible` and tap the button that `RefreshCommand` is bound to, then I have no run time errors.
When I leave `ExecuteIfPossible`, then the inner exception is

> Could not load file or assembly 'Uno.Foundation,
>   Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I don't even know what `ExecuteIfPossible` is to be honest. I just wanted to call `Execute(null)` but intellisense wouldn't let me (and that would not compile either). So this surely something to do with the Uno implmentation of ReactiveUI.

UPDATE2

In order for `Execute` to be available, I had to make `RefreshCommand` of type `ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit>`. Then I could write the following and everything works as expected.

```
RefreshCommand.Execute(Unit.Default).Subscribe().DisposeWith(Disposables);
```

UPDATE3

The question is pointless and should be "closed" as the issue has nothing to do with its title or its description. It's just me:

1. not using ReactiveUI properly
2. calling a Uno.Client method that throws an exception and falsy concluding that it was a ReactiveUI issue when it is not.

Thank you for those who took the time to help me.

Comment: Where does come from _ExecuteIfPossible_ ?

Comment: The issue is the same without ExecuteIfPossible by tapping on the button the command is bound to.

Comment: Of what type is your ReactiveCommand ? I think it should be *ReactiveCommand<Unit,Unit>*

Comment: I declared it as ReactiveCommand without types as I don't think it should matter. I often do that. I could be wrong but I don't think that's an issue.

Comment: You're right, may be Can you share a smal repro to look at ?

Comment: What's the inner exception? That's where the real issue will show up.

Comment: @AdriánRomero, I misled you. I don't have any issue when tapping on the button the command is bound to. The problem comes from `ExecuteIfPossible`. I'll update the question.

Comment: @François - Can you please make a [mcve] so we can see the error ourselves?